# Clicking on child element without triggering the parent

Tags: javascript, html, containers, parent

I'm trying to write a script that places images into containers. I'm suppose to be able to move the images around. 
The problem is I check for if I have an image to place or if the container is full and when I try to click the image in the container it runs the check first.

```
function isTemp()
        {
            if(temp == null)
            {
                alert("Please pick an item to place in the container");
            }
            else
            {
                holder = true;
            }
        }
        function fillLarge()
        {
            isTemp();
            if(holder)
            {
                if(largeArray[0] != undefined &&largeArray[1] != undefined &&largeArray[2] != undefined && largeArray[3] != undefined &&largeArray[4] != undefined &&largeArray[5] != undefined)
                {
                    alert('This crate is full');
                }
                else
                {
                    for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
                    {
                        if (largeArray[i] == undefined)
                        {
                            largeArray[i] = /*"<span id = '"+temp+"'onclick='temp=this.id; break;'>*/"<img src='image/"+temp+".jpg'/>"/*</span>"*/;
                            largeArray[i].id = temp;            
                            document.getElementById("la").innerHTML += largeArray[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    document.getElementById(temp).style.display="none";
                    temp = null;
                }
                holder = false;
            }
```

### }

the HTML

```
<div>
        <h3> LARGE CONTAINER </h3>
        <span id="la" onclick="fillLarge();"> 
        </span> </div>
```

How would I be able to click the images without clicking the div itself and triggering the check which would stop temp from getting the value?

Answer (score 1):

Prevent bubbling upwards, you can do so by returning false.

```
 <div>
    <h3> LARGE CONTAINER </h3>
    <span id="la" onclick="fillLarge(); return false;"></span>
 </div>
```

note: this also prevents default behavior (e.g. stops links from linking, etc). 
Some reading material explaining the basics of JS events: [Peter Paul Koch, Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try event.stopPropagation() - documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: Oops - good point - another ref is http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html - even though I point to the jQuery docs, it is not exclusive to jquery. There is additional info in daan's link